# React: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

i'm trying to get list of forms with axios in react

this is the function

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATE', payload: { loading: true } })
            const response = await axios

                .get(`${API_URL}/form`, {
                    userId: localStorage.getItem('userId'),
                    headers: {
                        authorization: localStorage.getItem('userId')
                    }

                })
            console.log(response)
                .catch((err) => {
                    if (err.response.status === 401) history.push('/login')
                    return dispatch({
                        type: 'SET_STATE',
                        payload: { loading: false, error: err.response.data.msg }
                    })
                })
            dispatch({
                type: 'SET_STATE', payload: {
                    data: response.data.form,
                    loading: false,
                },

            })
        }
        fetchData()
        return () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATE', payload: { loading: true, error: '' } })
        }
    }, [])
```

and this is the reducer

```js
const initialState = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: '',
}
const formReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_STATE':
            return { ...state, ...action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }

}
```

but i get this error :

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined

Comment: You are trying to catch the result of `console.log()` but logging to the console doesn't do anything. You should use either the `await` syntax everywhere or the `.then/.catch`, don't mix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You broke the promise chain by adding `console.log` between `get` and `catch`. Use the `console.log` in `then` instead like below :

Also you're mixing the `async/await` with `then`. Although, it will work `response` will not be what you expect. Just use the `then` chaining.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {
           dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATE', payload: { loading: true } })
           axios
               .get(`${API_URL}/form`, {
                    ...
                })

                // add the console in then
                .then(response=>{
                   console.log(response))
                   dispatch({
                     type: 'SET_STATE',
                     payload: {
                       data: response.data.form,
                       loading: false,
                     }
                   })
                 })
                
                .catch((err) => {
                    ...
                })
            
        }
        fetchData()
        return () => {
            dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATE', payload: { loading: true, error: '' } })
        }
    }, [])
```

Comment: Thank you, i added a data.map to get result but i get another error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @MounaSis just add your dispatch in `then`. I updated the code.